# Flex: Row based rendering in Datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I need to have custom rendering of each row in my datagrid. It is column based by default. Is there some way to achieve this?

If any one has tried this before or has any idea in this regard, then please share.

Thanks in advance.

Ashine.

Comment: Actually ,I need to render altogether different data in a row when its clicked. My requiremtn is like this, initially I am showing some 5 Major attributes in all rows but when user clicks on one of the rows, I want to disply total 8 attributes in that row keeping other rows unaffected. Fot this I thought, having a row based renderer will resolve the issue. If you have any better ideas to implement this then plz share.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is different colors, there is an [alternatingItemColors](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#style:alternatingItemColors) style in DataGrid's base class `ListBase`. You can set an array of colors.

> The colors to use for the backgrounds of the items in the list. The value is an array of two or more colors. The backgrounds of the list items alternate among the colors in the array.
>
> For DataGrid controls, all items in a row have the same background color, and each row's background color is determined from the array of colors.

What kind of customization are you looking for?

Comment: Dear Amar,I need to render altogether different data in the row when its clicked. My requiremtn is like this,  initially I am showing some 5 Major attributes in all rows but when user clicks on one I want to disply total 8 attributes in that row keeping other rows unaffected. Fot this I thought, having a row based renderer will resolve the issue. If you have any better ideas to implement this then plz share.